# Plotly slider updating multiple plots instead of one

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am making a diesel cycle plot and I would like to find out how to make my slider only affect one chart, ie. t-s diagram shouldn't change when you change the values for compression ratio.

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import math
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
pio.renderers.default='browser'

# Constants and assumptions

bore = .078
stroke = .062
vd = math.pi * (bore/2)**(2) * stroke
rk = 15 #typical compression ratio for small diesel engines
V2 = vd / (rk - 1)
V1 = rk * V2
T1 = 300 #kelvin assumed atmospheric
P1 = 101.325 #kpa assumed athmospheric
k = 1.4 #assumed ideal gas
rc = 2.5 #for high efficiency operation
S1 = 10 #change. for testing
cp = 1.0038
cv = 0.717

# equations based on value
P2 = P1 * (rk)**k
T2 = T1 * (rk)**(k-1)
P3 = P2
T3 = rc * T2
V3 = V2 * rc
V4 = V1
P4 = P3 * (V3 / V4)**k
T4 = T3 * (P4 / P3)**((k-1)/k)
m = (P1*V1)/(0.287*T1)
S3 = S1 + m * cp * np.log(T3/T2)


V = [V1]
P = [P1]
T = [T1]
S = [S1]


points12 = 100
points34 = 100
points23 = 100
points41 = 100


for i in range(1, points12 + 1):
    Vi = V1 * (V2 / V1) ** (i / points12)
    Pi = P1 * (V1 / Vi) ** k
    V.append(Vi)
    P.append(Pi)
    
for i in range(0, points23 + 1):
    Ti = T2 * (T3 / T2) ** (i / points23)
    Si = S1 + m * cp * np.log(Ti / T2)
    T.append(Ti)
    S.append(Si)

for i in range(0, points34 + 1):
    Vi = V3 * (V4 / V3) ** (i / points34)
    Pi = P3 * (V3 / Vi) ** k
    V.append(Vi)
    P.append(Pi)

for i in range(0, points41 + 1):
    Ti = T4 * (T1 / T4) ** (i / points41)
    Si = S3 + m * cv * np.log(Ti / T4)
    T.append(Ti)
    S.append(Si)

V.extend([V1, V1])
P.extend([P1, P1])
T.extend([T1, T1])
S.extend([S1, S1])

fig = make_subplots(cols=2)


slider_steps = []
for rk in range(10, 31):
    V2 = vd / (rk - 1)
    V1 = rk * V2
    P2 = P1 * (rk)**k
    T2 = T1 * (rk)**(k-1)
    P3 = P2
    T3 = rc * T2
    V3 = V2 * rc
    V4 = V1
    P4 = P3 * (V3 / V4)**k
    T4 = T3 * (P4 / P3)**((k-1)/k)
    V = [V1]
    P = [P1]
    effi = (1-(1/(rk**(k-1)))*((((rc)**k)-1)/(k*(rc-1))))*100
    clr= V2*1000000

    # Recalculate the points using the new rk value
    for i in range(1, points12 + 1):
        Vi = V1 * (V2 / V1) ** (i / points12)
        Pi = P1 * (V1 / Vi) ** k
        V.append(Vi)
        P.append(Pi)
        
    # for i in range(1, points23 + 1):
    #     Ti = T2 * (T3 / T2) ** (i / points23)
    #     Si = S1 + m * cp * np.log(Ti / T2)
    #     T.append(Ti)
    #     S.append(Si)

    for i in range(0, points34 + 1):
        Vi = V3 * (V4 / V3) ** (i / points34)
        Pi = P3 * (V3 / Vi) ** k
        V.append(Vi)
        P.append(Pi)

    # for i in range(1, points41 + 1):
    #     Ti = T4 * (T1 / T4) ** (i / points41)
    #     Si = S3 + m * cv * np.log(Ti / T4)
    #     T.append(Ti)
    #     S.append(Si)

    V.extend([V1, V1])
    P.extend([P1, P1])
    # T.extend([T1, T1])
    # S.extend([S1, S1])
    
    
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        label=f"rk = {rk}  engine efficiency in percent: {effi} clearance/combustion chamber vol: {clr}cm^3 cut off ratio: {rc}   mass={m}",
        args=[{"y": [P], "x": [V]}],
    )
    slider_steps.append(step)

sliders = [
    dict(
        active=15,
        currentvalue={"prefix": "Compression Ratio (rk): "},
        pad={"t": 50},
        steps=slider_steps,
    )
]

fig.add_scatter(x=V, y=P, mode='lines+markers', name=  'Diesel Cycle PV', row=1, col=1)
fig.add_scatter(x=S, y=T, mode='lines+markers', name='Diesel Cycle TS', row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders,
    title='Diesel Cycle P-V Diagram',
    xaxis=dict(title='Volume (m^3)'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Pressure (kPa)'),
)

fig.show()
```

Issue: the moment I move the slider, the t-s plot becomes a copy of the p-v plot.

Currently I'm just starting out in plotly and python so I'm still quite unsure of this code and I need more study on it. Initial code was written by ChatGPT and I studied it for a few days, then looked for information on the internet about how to do the isentropic curve with loop and how to add a second plot.

I have suspicions on the `step = dict( args=[{"y", [P]], "x": [V]}])` and I need help as well understanding how to specify which x and y of which plot to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicions were correct, you need to specify in each step `args` the trace (indices) to update (default behaviour is to apply changes to all traces).

Note that `args` refer to the arguments passed to the specified `method`, so you can refer to the corresponding Plotly.js function reference to understand how it works. With `method="update"`, the step `args` should comply with the [`Plotly.update()`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate) function signature :

> `Plotly.update(graphDiv, data_update, layout_update, [, traceIndices])`

which translates to specifying `args` as `[ data_update, layout_update, traceIndices ]`.

Also, note the trace indices are zero-based and correspond to the order of creation of those traces (the p-v trace is created first so its index is 0).

```
step = dict(
    method="update",
    label=f"rk = {rk}  engine efficiency in percent: {effi} clearance/combustion chamber vol: {clr}cm^3 cut off ratio: {rc}   mass={m}",
    args=[{"y": [P], "x": [V]}, {}, [0]],
)
```

Comment: Thanks! You have no idea how much the tiny snippet " {}, [0]]," saved my sanity hahahahahahhaha I was already so bored reading the entire documentation of plotly.graph_objects.Figures looking for the culprit behind choosing which one to update. Thanks again